# Inserting string in FOR BIT DATA column in DB2

Tags: db2, hex

When i try inserting a string value in a column in DB2, which is defined as **CHAR(15) FOR BIT DATA**, i notice that it gets converted into some other format, probably hexadecimal.

On retrieving the data, i get a byte array, and on trying to convert it back to ASCII, using **System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString**, i get back a string of some junk characters.

Anyone faced this issue?
Any resolution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For Bit Data prevents the code page convertion between the client and the server. This is normally used to insert binary data, instead of strings.

Please, take a look at this forum, where many cases are proposed and solved: http://www.dbforums.com/db2/1663992-bit-data.html

You could eventually make a cast to database page (it depends you platform)

```
CAST(c1 AS CHAR(n) FOR SBCS DATA)

CAST (<forbitdataexpression> AS [VARCHAR|CHAR][(<n>)] FOR [SBCS|DBCS] DATA)
```

References

- http://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/180874-problem-db2-field-type-char-n-bit-data
- http://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/182124-function-convert-bit-data-column-string
- http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023459.html